# Save file from Dropzone Vuejs in a folder

Tags: laravel, vue.js, dropzone.js

I have a dropzone component:

```
<vue-dropzone id="drop1" :options="dropOptions"  @vdropzone-complete="afterComplete"></vue-dropzone>
```

and my dropzone option is :

```
dropOptions: {
                  url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
                  maxFilesize: 2, // MB
                  maxFiles: 1,
                  thumbnailWidth: 180, // px
                  thumbnailHeight: 150,
                  addRemoveLinks: true,
                  showRemoveLink: false,
                  acceptedFiles: "image/*",
                  paramName: "file",
              },
```

I have three questions:

1) i want to save the image file which user uploaded into a folder (storage/temporary) before i save in database

2)after save in this temporary file when user enter all other information, then remove this image file from temporary folder and save it in Database

3) i dont know what should i write in url also

i really appreciate if anyone can help me

Comment: 1) Save it in LocalStorage and 2)Delete it from Local Storage on successfull upload

Comment: @Badgy: thanks but may i know how to do it?